# AJAX and getting recent database entries

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am working on a web application that will query a database for messages and display them to the browser. I am first of all retrieving the list of messages server side on visiting the site and then displaying the ones that are there. But then I want to use AJAX to periodically check for messages again and update the DOM with the new ones.

However, I don't want to refresh the entire list. Just inject the most recent messages into a table. I am using MySQL, PHP and mootools and I am really just looking to hear ideas of the best practice on how to achieve this. Sending an array of every message ID on the screen via AJAX and then comparing it to what is in the DB is my current solution but this seems extremely dirty.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: How large is this list of messages?

Comment: Very large, 10,000+ unless I periodically clear and backup. We need the messages kept in some format though.

Comment: Does the database message table contain a timestamp for when new messages are added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps instead of retrieving the entire message table from the database, you could instead query using the timestamp as a way of only getting the newest messages since the last time you checked.  All you'd have to do is store the timestamp each time you ran your ajax check for new messages, and query the database for messages > timestamp.
Then no checking is required, you can just add whatever is returned from the query to your browser list.

Comment: May be redundant, but just a reminder to not use a timestamp sent by the client (as it may be inaccurate) but instead to use only a serverside timestamp :)